# How to create a collection in Julia?

Tags: collections, julia

This seems like a really basic question, but can't find the answer. How do I create a collection in Julia? For example, I want to open a text file and parse each line to create an (iterable or otherwise) collection. Obviously I don't know how many elements there are in advance.

I can iterate through the lines like this

```
I = each_line(open(fileName,"r"))
state = start(I)

while !done(I, state)
  (i, state) = next(I, state)

  println(i)
end
```

But I don't know how to put each i into an array or other collection. I tried

```
map( i -> println(i), each_line(open(fileName,"r") ) )
```

But got the error

> no method map(Function,EachLine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
lines = String[]
for line in each_line(open(fileName))
  push!(lines, line)
end
```

And then `lines` contains the list of lines. You need the `String` in the first line to make the array extensible.

Answer (score 4):

Standard collections and supported operations are mainly covered in the [standard library](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib) documentation.

Specifically, the [Deques](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#dequeues) section covers all of the operations supported by the 1d `Array` type (vector), including `push!` and `pop!` as well as insertion, resizing, etc.

Omar's answer is correct, and I will just add a small qualification: `String[]` creates a 1d array of `String`s. The same constructor syntax may be used for example to create `Int[]`, `Float[]`, or even `Any[]` vectors. The latter type may hold objects of any type.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that there is a short-cut for the special case `Any[]`, namely `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your Julia version, you may also be able to write `collect(eachline(open("LICENSE.md")))` or `[eachline(open("LICENSE.md"))...]`. I think these won't work in 0.1.x versions but will working in newer 0.2 development versions (which are recommended at this point – 0.2 is on its way soon).

Comment: Nice, I'd written that function myself, glad to see it's in the library now. (And collect is a better name than arrayof, which is what I used.)